# Can't get property from object when redirecting with "Header" function

Tags: php, http-redirect

I'm trying to display a inserted product after it is inserted. It looks like the object is empty.

This is what I use to redirect ('Inventario' controller)

```
public function insertarAction(){
// insertarProducto returns true or false
    if($this->producto->insertarProducto()) {

        Flash::addMessage('Prenda ingresada correctamente');
        $this->redirect('/inventario/ingreso-correcto');

    } else {
        Flash::addMessage('Error al ingresar prenda', FLASH::WARNING);
        View::renderTemplate('Inventario/nuevo.html',[
                'user' => Auth::getUser(),
                'producto' => $this->producto,
                'controller' => 'inventario'
            ]);
    }
}
```

This redirects me to the html I need but without the 'producto' object.

I created the product object in a `before` method that runs before the other methods are called.

This is what  'redirect' function does (it is on my core/controller class):

```
public function redirect($url){
        header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $url, true, 303);
        exit;   
}
```

This is the ingreso-correcto HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Codigo</th>
        <td>{{ producto.codigo }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Color</th>  
        <td>{{ producto.color }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Cantidad en stock</th>
        <td>{{ producto.cantidad }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Descripcion de producto</th>
        <td>{{ producto.descripcion }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Precio</th>
        <td>{{ producto.precio }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Costo</th>
        <td>{{ producto.costo }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Descuento</th>
        <td>{{ producto.descuento }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Coleccion</th>
        <td>{{ producto.coleccion }}</td>
    </tr>
        <th>Ganancia</th>
        <td>{{ producto.ganancia }}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

How can I get the `producto` object after i've used the `redirect` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not write, what does the `insertarProducto()` function do, but if it does not write a product id to user session, it must do it, or You have to code it in `insertarAction()` controller function.

If `inventario` is a kind of a shopping basket, You could also get access to it and try to retrieve last added Product for current User.

**Another solution**

You could also attach `producto` id to Your redirect URL, but it is not as clean as using session.

```
$this->redirect('/inventario/ingreso-correcto/{producto.id}');
```

Comment: why should it write a product id? I tried writing the whole product object into the session and it works but I don't think that's the best way to go. Your solution would be writing the product ID and then retrieving it from the DB?

Comment: @DiegoRios storing objects in Session is possible, I guess, but I wouldn't advise it. Storing only an ID is enough. After redirect, inside a controller, You could retrieve a whole Product object from DB by its ID taken from Session, and assign it to a View, and of course remove ID from Session after use.